# JS library (with drag n drop) compatible with iOS and regular browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, drag-and-drop

Does anyone know of a JS framework that has drag and drop functionality and is compatible with mobile (iOS) and regular browsers?

I currently have a web-based app and it is a hassle to make its drag'n'drop functionality  work on iOS... I wish there was one that would do it for both...

Comment: Santa, I'm looking for the same. By any change did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have a bounty on another question, but as soon as that one expires I'll put one on this one. Appreciate your support of this effort. I think there's an great need for a plug-in that will automate compatibility of existing drag and drop apps with iOS. Currently there's no easy solution, but rather maintaining two versions of the same app. Remember the days when we had to do the same for different browsers. Finally MS came to senses, not it's Apple's turn... :)

Comment: One of my friend implemented a javascript library doing the same thing, draggable.js, i'll verify tomorrow if I can put it on google code

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Champigny Thanks. Anything helps. Clearly this topic is of great interest to many. Tablet market exploded overnight and left  a huge incompatibility gap.

Comment: Can't believe nobody mentioned YUI, they have full gesture support and custom events.

Answer (score 27):

Here's two built in jQuery:

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/mobiledragdrop.html

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/

There is also the jquery mobile framework (which does not have drag and drop nativly):
http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: steventon.co.uk library does not work properly on an iPad, you don't see the boxes moving and once clicked you get a copy in the bottom of your page

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the first one. It is not really a drag and drop on a mobile device. It is click to select -- click target to drop, which is a major departure from the user experience point of view. Second link one does not seem to work on my android.

Comment: @santa part of an issue a library doesn't exist (and the library choose click to select) is because scrolling and drag and drop can't be distinguished between on a touch device.  Basically let's assume you have a gaint draggable that takes up half of the web page.  Now the user decides to scroll down to the other half of the web page.  Guess what, the draggable element will now move and the user attempts to scroll.  Basically you are forced into creating two applications for both the iphone and desktop.

Comment: Assuming the interface has been structured so the above isn't an issue, it would be nice if such a library already existed.

Comment: @Lime check out http://demos.kendoui.com/dragdrop/index.html There are some IE issues, but it does work on android device.

Comment: @santa glad you found a solution ( or atleast something closer to one )

Answer (score 14):

I'm a big fan of [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).

Here's there drag and drop demo - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/dragdrop/.

**Note:** Tested on my iPhone 4 in Safari.

Comment: But it does not seem to work on a regular browser... I just tried in FF.

Comment: It seem to be a pure mobile version -- did not work in my FF on a laptop... I'm looking for universal solution...

Comment: You might want to just use jQuery then.  Mobile drag and drop/UI frameworks are typically based on webkit

Answer (score 10):

[JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/) is trying to support a large variety of [platforms](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/platforms.html)

And here is a specific plugins for [Drag and Drop](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/mobiledragdrop.html)

Answer (score 8):

Try dojo. It works pretty well and it is a relatively mature toolkit. http://dojotoolkit.org/

Comment: I tried DnD on my Android phone and it did not work... I'm looking for universal solution... Thanks for mentioning this one though -- very cool.

Comment: @santa I just wanted to let you know that dojo 1.7 is about to come out and it is advertised to have much better support for drag and drop and mobile capabilities. Maybe you should check it out again. http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/dnd

Answer (score 6):

Check out [SproutCore](http://sproutcore.com/). It's a framework created by former Apple engineers and is used by Apple in MobileMe and iCloud web apps. It has [SC.Drag](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Drag.html) which works with both mouse and touch events.

Comment: Cool! Do they have demos at all? The easiest way for me to test is to hit demo both with browser and my phone.

Answer (score 4):

[interact.js](https://github.com/taye/interact.js#interactjs) is a standalone and lightweight drag-and-drop, resize and multi-touch gesture javascript module. It works on iOS, Android, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE9+ with support for interacting with HTML and SVG elements. Something to note in advance is that it's up to the developer to respond to drag events but I think that's a good thing.

To allow the whole page to be panned by dragging, you could use:

```
// make an Interactable of the document body element
interact(document.body)
// make a draggable of the Interactable
  .draggable({
    // on(drag)move
    onmove: function (event) {
      x += event.dx;
      y += event.dy;

      // translate the document body by the change in pointer position
      document.body.style.translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
    }
  })
```

Comment: Upvoted... Been using interact for my [custom map generator for my new web-based game](http://i.gyazo.com/8a6fbb9faff96e56ec237a0971e43734.gif). It's so simple to integrate. If only there would be a minified version for drag and drop with intertia only :)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.kendoui.com/ this should work. Has d'n'd too, even though it's still in Beta.

Comment: Looks very nice, although I'd be hesitatnt to transition to a library that's based around pre-released version of HTML. Also, I did not seem to find drag and drop functionality...

Comment: Here's the drag and drop: http://demos.kendoui.com/dragdrop/index.html

"pre-released version of HTML" ?

Comment: Thanks, I must be blind... I meant HTML5. It is unofficially supported by some browsers.

Comment: OK, this is one of the runner-ups for sure. It worked on my android and in FF, however IE9 threw a bunch of errors. If those are resolved I'd be very interested! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

- zepto (smallest, iOS 4+, Android 2.2+, webOS 1.4.5+)
- jquery, jquerymobile, jqtouch
- prototype
- sencha, senchatouch

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery UI for drag and drop and an additional library that maps touch events to their mouse event analogs.I think this should solve your problem:

https://github.com/yeco/jquery-ui-touch-punch

> To add touch events, just include the jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js
>   script after your jquery.ui scripts.

DEMOS:

http://furf.com/exp/touch-punch/

Comment: Hmm, we may have a winner. The demos worked for me on a browser and Android! Can someone please test this on iOs?

Comment: jQuery UI's full suite of demos have been tested and passed on iOS. Check the official site to see the demos http://touchpunch.furf.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its exactly what you're looking for, but you could try [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) or maybe [XUI](http://xuijs.com/).

Comment: I am looking for a solution to make my current jQuery drag and drop functionality supported on mobile platforms, IN ADDITION to existing compatibility on web browsers and WITHOUT re-writing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building web apps for ios you must try jquery mobile.

Comment: I have a web app and I need to add support for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

hi there i use this jquery plugin:
https://github.com/LuvDaSun/jdrag

It provides some drag events

let me know if you find any bugs, the code is quite new!

Answer (score 0):

This is still in alpha:  http://prettydiff.com/jsgui

It is persistent even after you close or refresh your browser and it will work in any modern browser.  Furthermore it is not a framework.  You can use this without other frameworks and you can customize it to do what you want.