# Drag and Drop functionality in iOS

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I wanted to know is there any API for Drag and Drop functionality in iOS.
If API is not available, is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Hi Cathy, did Dragkit work for you? I don't see any samples for Dragkit. Could you share brief code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of alpha but might help: [dragkit](http://iosdevgoodies.joostschuur.com/dragkit-ios-framework-drag-drop-behavior)

Comment: article not found in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Answered pretty thoroughly here

[JS library (with drag n drop) compatible with iOS and regular browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168514/js-library-with-drag-n-drop-compatible-with-ios-and-regular-browsers)

Included libraries that work on IOS and all browsers at the same time.