# Drag and Drop Javascript on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, ios6

Hi all I have the following code for my drag and drop feature. However I need to adapt it to work on iOS. Being rather new at Javascript I'm not really sure how to go about adapting the code I already have to work with what I have read.

My code is as follows:

```
            function allowDrop(ev){
                            ev.preventDefault();
                    }

                    function drag(ev){
                            var drag = ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);

                    }

                    function drop(ev){
                            ev.preventDefault();
                            var image= ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
                          if ( image == ev.target.id) {
                            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
                            }
                          else {

                          }
                    }
```

Any help would be great. I assume the problem is I need some sort of listener for the touch events?

Comment: You'd better use javascript instead of writing vanilla javascript to make it work on other platforms. 
Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168514/js-library-with-drag-n-drop-compatible-with-ios-and-regular-browsers